# How to get back first character to end of previous line with Vim

Tags: vim

I have following code:

```
mapping make_episode(string series, string title, string episode, array date)
{
    return ([ "series":series, "episode":episode, "title":title, "date":date ]);
}

void print_episode(mapping episode)
{
    write("  %-30s %10s %-30s (%{%d.%})\n", 
          episode->series, episode->episode, episode->title, episode->date);
}
```

I want to get all "`{`" (opening curly braces) at beginning of lines to be moved to end of previous lines.

I searched for it on the net but could not find it.

What command do I give in Vim to do above task (moving all such characters in one go)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match lines of interest with `:global` and then join them with `:join`

```
g/^{$/-join
```

(use `join!` if you don't need an extra space).

To go step by step:

```
g/.../...     ----> for every line matching regex do a command
 /^{$/        ----> regex: single left brace on a line
      -join   ----> join previous line with the next one (i.e. the currently matched line)
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. It will be great if you can add explanation also.

Comment: @mso Not too much of a fancy stuff but added anyway.

Comment: How can we modify it so that it will work even if there are any number of space characters before or after the `{`.

Comment: @mso Edit the regex. Sort of `/^\s*{\s*$/`

Comment: [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4419802/matt) You have just read my mind :). I figured out the same solution and scrolled down to see the answers and saw yours! Great! It means I am learning the vim philosophy.

Comment: @SergioAraujo If I'd only known it ;-)

Comment: The only difference is the exclamation to remove the extra space `join!` instead of `join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `J` - note, a capital (with shift).

Comment: That I will have to do for each `{`. I want to give a command to shift all `{` in document.

Comment: In which case you can use `:%s/\n{/{/g`

Comment: Yes this works - but not if there is a space before `{`